# 3D visualization of terrain data and orthophoto using GRASS NVIZ via QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, 3d, orthophoto, nviz

How can I make 3D visualization of terrain data and orthophoto using GRASS NVIZ via QGIS? I am quite new with GRASS. I have only managed to get a 3D view of the terrain so far.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you could try to add a z value in your ortho photo from the terrain and use NVIZ on the ortho photo just like you did with the terrain